# SqlDataSource makes DropdownList results to one item that is duplicated in the list for displaying in GridView

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a Visual Studio 2010 asp.net page in VB where I have joined multiple tables with the `SqlDataSource` to display specific columns in a gridview. After the table join, I have a dropdownlist where I want it to display only those rows whose "SKillGroup" column value is equivalent to the selected item on the dropdownlist. However when running the page, the dropdownlist only has one selected item (the item being Hardware) which is duplicated in the list.

My problem is how do I make it so that the dropdownlist shows all three items of 'Hardware' 'Software' and 'Network' and depending on the selected search populate it into the gridview?

Here is my code for dropdownlist and gridview

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            DataSourceID="ProblemDataSource" DataTextField="SkillGroup" 
            DataValueField="SkillGroup">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Hardware</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Software</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Network</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

     <asp:GridView ID="ProblemGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="ProblemDataSource" style="margin-top: 0px" 
            AllowPaging="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProblemID" HeaderText="ProblemID" 
                    SortExpression="ProblemID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" 
                    SortExpression="CustomerID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Summary" HeaderText="Summary" 
                    SortExpression="Summary" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateLogged" HeaderText="DateLogged" 
                    SortExpression="DateLogged" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateUpdated" HeaderText="DateUpdated" 
                    SortExpression="DateUpdated" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
                    SortExpression="Status" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Priority" HeaderText="Priority" 
                    SortExpression="Priority" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" 
                    SortExpression="Surname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SkillGroupID" HeaderText="SkillGroupID" 
                    SortExpression="SkillGroupID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SkillGroup" HeaderText="SkillGroup" 
                    SortExpression="SkillGroup" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr1" HeaderText="Expr1" SortExpression="Expr1" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr2" HeaderText="Expr2" SortExpression="Expr2" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="NoteID" HeaderText="NoteID" 
                    SortExpression="NoteID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ResolutionID" HeaderText="ResolutionID" 
                    SortExpression="ResolutionID" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my `SqlDataSource` for the tables join and filtering skills group column for dropdown list

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ProblemDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT p.ProblemID, p.CustomerID, p.Summary, p.DateLogged, p.DateUpdated, s.Status, pr.Priority, t.Name, t.Surname, sg.SkillGroupID, sg.SkillGroup, ho.Name AS Expr1, ho.Surname AS Expr2, p.NoteID, p.ResolutionID FROM Problem AS p LEFT OUTER JOIN Status AS s ON p.StatusID = s.StatusID INNER JOIN HelpdeskOperator AS ho ON p.HelpdeskID = ho.HelpdeskID LEFT OUTER JOIN Priority AS pr ON p.PriorityID = pr.PriorityID LEFT OUTER JOIN [Skill Group] AS sg ON p.SkillGroupID = sg.SkillGroupID INNER JOIN Technician AS t ON p.ProblemID = t.ProblemID AND s.StatusID = t.StatusID AND pr.PriorityID = t.PriorityID WHERE ([SkillGroup] = @SkillGroup) " 
        <FilterParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="newparameter" />
        </FilterParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="SkillGroup" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="SkillGroup" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have also posted a link to the screenshot that displays what the problem is below

http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0356716/Helpdesk.html

Can someone please advise me on this as it has been bugging me for a while.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined your DropDownList in the following way:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
     DataSourceID="ProblemDataSource" DataTextField="SkillGroup" 
     DataValueField="SkillGroup">
       <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Hardware</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Software</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Network</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

For a start, you can't have all items selected. Only Hardware will be selected as it's the first in the list.

This leads to your second problem;

The query you then run is (reduced for brevity):

```
SELECT blah
FROM Tables
 WHERE ([SkillGroup] = @SkillGroup)
```

Which, of course, will be `Hardware` in your example above.

So you will only ever get skill groups of type `Hardware` back. As it's the data source for your drop down list, you'll therefore only get 'Hardware' in the list.

Note also, you get Hardware **twice**. This is because you have **two** records with a SkillGroup of Hardware.

You have a couple of choices here to start with. You can either not make your drop down list databound:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
     <asp:ListItem>Hardware</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Software</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Network</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Or you can bind your DropDownList to another data source, which simply runs the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SkillGroup FROM [Skill Group]
```

UPDATE:

For the second part of your question, what you can use the [FilterParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bfya48%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) section of SqlDataSource;

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ProblemDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="YOUR QUERY WITHOUT THE WHERE CLAUSE"
        FilterExpression="SkillGroup='{0}'"> 
        <FilterParameters>
             <asp:ControlParameter 
                 Name="SkillGroup" 
                 ControlID="DropDownList1" 
                 PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </FilterParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Make sure you only `DataBind` DropDownList1 once, on Page_Init or similar, and don't rebuild it every time (check for `!Page.IsPostBack`)

However, if you want to query against the datasource everytime (which is more efficient for large data sets), then I suspect the issue here is that your DropDownList value is being wiped out with each PostBack. How are you calling `DataBind`, and are you remembering, for the DropDownList, to check if `!Page.IsPostBack`?

Comment: Thank You Dash, I decided to bind the dropdownlist to another datasource with the query from your answer which now displays the correct items in the list. But it does not search and displays the selected item results into the gridview. Please could you advise how I can go round this problem?

Comment: When you select another item (like `Software`) in your dropdownlist, does the page post back?

Comment: Yes it does, but nothing happens to the gridview none of the items that are selected display anything in the gridview.

Comment: I've added something for you to try,

Comment: Hi there, I get the following error when I use those filter parameters  **Literal Content FilterExpression="[Skill Group]= '{0}'"> is not allowed within a System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource** Please could you advise of could be the issue as the code seems to be correct unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @JennyP I've updated my answer; the FilterExpression should not contain a space - It's referencing the table, not the column, which is wrong. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much Dash, it now works, thanks for all your time and help, greatly appreciated!!!